# Does Juniper ScreenOS support IPCOMP?

Tags: ipsec, juniper, netscreen, screenos

Given an oldish Juniper Netscreen device running ScreenOS 6.2 (Juniper [NS5GT-ADSL](http://www.juniper.net/support/products/screenos/ns5gt/)), would it support IPCOMP payload compression ([RFC 2393](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2393.txt)) in IPSEC tunnels? If so, any reference on how to set it up?

Comment: I wish I still had access to my old 5GT to verify, but I don't believe so (and hence not a real answer).  http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/screenos/screenos6.3.0/630_ce_VPN.pdf doesn't show such an option, and I don't recall any cli command that referenced ipcomp or compression at all for IPSEC tunnels on a Netscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current [ScreenOS CLI reference guide for IPv4](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/screenos/screenos6.3.0/630_ipv4_cli.pdf) is not documenting much compression-related in general or IPCOMP-specific commands in particular. Looks like it is not supported.